# get attribute to create configurable product

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-attribute, attribute-set

i want to create configurable product.

[image: see this]

when i select attribute set how can i get related attribute to create configurable product?

i use this code to select attribute

```
jQuery('#attribute_set_id').on('change', function() {
    var a=(jQuery('#attribute_set_id').val());
    <?php     
        $html='';
        $att_id="<script>document.write(a)</script>";
        $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->setAttributeSetFilter($att_id)->getItems();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
        {
            if($attribute->getIsGlobal()==1 &&  $attribute->getIsVisible()==1 && $attribute->getIsConfigurable()==1 && $attribute->getFrontendInput()=='select' )
            {
                $id=$attribute->getId();
                $html.= $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
                $html.= "<input class='chk_attr validate-one-required' type=checkbox name=attribute[] value=$id >";
                $html.= '<br>';
            }
        }
    ?>
    jQuery('#check_fieldset_attr').html("<?php echo $html;?>");
});
```

but it not work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get all attribute by using this sript

```
<?php
    require_once('app/Mage.php');
    Mage::app();

    $aa=array(4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);
    foreach($aa as $abc)
    {

    echo '<br><br><br>';
    echo $abc.'<br>';
    $attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->setAttributeSetFilter($abc)->getItems();
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute)
        {
            if($attribute->getIsGlobal()==1 &&  $attribute->getIsVisible()==1 && $attribute->getIsConfigurable()==1 && $attribute->getFrontendInput()=='select' )
            {
                $id=$attribute->getId();
                echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
                echo '<br>';
                }
            }
        }

    ?>
```